# Create an interruptible sleep thread in Python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I'm just starting to read how to use threads in Python on my own so I have limited knowledge on how to resolve my problem. Here it is :

I've got a table in my db in which each row has a 'state'. The state might change constantly and when it gets a specific value, I wish to start a timer of 15 minutes. At the end of that timer, I want to write something in log files but if the 'state' loose that specific value, I want to be able to stop the timer.

```
# If component is not in room
if data[0][0] != data[1][0]:

    # If it is in the corridor
    if data[0][0] == data[1][1]:
        #end timer    <----
        #change position
        cursor.execute( """UPDATE Reservation
                SET localisation = '{}'
                WHERE reservationID = {}""".format( data[1][0], reservID ) )

    # If it is not in the corridor either
    else:
        print( "Le matériel a été lu sur un lecteur ne reconnaissant pas sa localisation" )
        print( "Vous n'avez pas passé le matériel sur le lecteur de '{}' au couloir".format( data[0][0] ) )
        #envoieMail
        exit( 6 )

# If it is in the room
else:
    #Change position
    cursor.execute( """UPDATE Reservation
            SET localisation = '{}'
            WHERE reservationID = {}""".format( data[1][1], reservID ) )
    #start timer     <----
```

I can start a thread alright. The thing is that I want to be able to find it back and stop it when the 'position' change.
Maybe this is not the best way to do what I want, if so, I'll be glad to have some advices!

Thank you.

EDIT : I've been thinking about getting the handler of the thread, put it in the db table (along with the state, in another column) and get it back from there to stop it. But I've read online that we can't kill thread ? But I can kill a process, so maybe multiprocessing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code that executes in response to changes to field values in a database, you might consider designing a trigger using the database's procedure and trigger coding methods.  However, such triggers are generally limited to performing operations on the database itself and cannot do much outside of the database system.  In your case, you could have a table that holds information about pending log writes.  This table could have fields such as a timestamp when the request was entered and a copy of the state field.

Having code execute only to wait several minutes before it does something is usually not a recommended approach.  You might consider running some code using cron scheduler that checks something every 1 minute (that is the most frequent interval that cron uses).  For example, in your case, you might run some code that checks the table holding pending log write information (timestamp field and copy of state field) against the current time (to see if 15 minutes has lapsed) and the state field value to determine whether to write the log file or not.  This code might also delete the request from the table once it becomes irrelevant.